# Create dynamic UI using R/Shiny where user input toggles parameter from a constant to a range

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and making an app where the output will ultimately be a plot of points produced using a function evaluated over a user-imposed range of variation in the x-axis parameter. There are 20 possible parameters from which the user can choose 1 to impose as x, but the rest of these parameters are also used by the function as single values. I want to make the app such that:

1. All of the 20 variables are visible in the app as single-value sliders
2. The user can change 1 of these single-value sliders at a time to a range slider by selecting the name of the parameter pertinent to the slider from a drop-down list
3. Only 1 slider at a time can be a range slider, meaning that a slider previously selected to produce a range of values should revert to some single default value when a different slider is selected to produce a range

So far I have succeeded in only producing one slider that can be manipulated using the drop-down list. In ui.R, I simple have `uiOutput("ui")`, while in server.R:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
var <- reactive(switch(input$var_param,
                 "K_As1" = (value <- c(10,20)),
                 "K_Ap1" = (value <- c(10,15))
))

output$ui <- renderUI({
    # Depending on input$var_param, we'll generate a different
    # slider component and reload it with a range.
    sliderInput("ui", label = input$var_param, 0, 50, var())
  })
})
```

So I'm fairly stuck with this. In order to have the single-value default sliders, it seems like it would be necessary to write this into ui.R; however, that means they cannot be dynamic as ui.R is run only once when the app is launched. It may be necessary to use `if` statements, perhaps? Any pointers on where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to create a dynamic UI with shiny. Here is one possible solution for your problem. The main idea is to use a reactive variable to store the the name of the selected variable. Only the selected variable in the `selectInput` will have a range slider and the remaining variables will have a single value sliders with a default value. An associated observer with the `selectInput` will change the name of the selected variable and the `rangeUI` will be rendered again.

I hope it could help you to build you dynamic UI.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, uiOutput('controls')),
    column(6, plotOutput('plot1', height = 500))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # define the data frame to use
  dat <- mtcars
  # name of available data frame
  varNames <-  names(dat)
  # define defaul values as the first value in each column
  defaultValues <- as.numeric(dat[1,])
  # store the selected variable in a reactive variable 
  rv <- reactiveValues(selected = varNames[1])

  # dynamically creates a set of sliders
  output$controls <- renderUI({
    div(
      fluidRow(
        column(3, 
          selectInput("select", "Variables", varNames, selected=varNames[1])
        ),
        column(9, uiOutput("rangeUI"))
      )
    )
  })

  output$rangeUI <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:length(varNames), function(k) {
      # get min and max value
      minmax <- c(round(min(dat[[varNames[k]]])), round(max(dat[[varNames[k]]])) )
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          if (rv$selected == varNames[k]) {
            # a slider range will created only is the variable is selected
            sliderInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], 
              min = minmax[1], max = minmax[2], value = minmax)
          } else {
            # otherwise uses single value with a default value
            sliderInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], 
              min = minmax[1], max = minmax[2], value = defaultValues[k])
          }
        )
      )
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    # changes in this variable will make the UI "controls" to be rendered again
    rv$selected <- input$select
  })

  # plot dat
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    # get the correct id name for the current slider
    id <- paste0("slider_", rv$selected)
    cat("id", id, "\n")
    # get the value from the input
    val = input[[id]]
    # plot all points of the selected variable
    plot(dat[,rv$selected])
    # fill out the points that are greater or equal to the value
    points(dat[ dat[,rv$selected] >= val, rv$selected, drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Jon, I updated the solution to meet your requirements. I hope it works for you now.

Comment: You're welcome.Here is a good article about reactivity on Shiny: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html